# Replace "\" with the ""

Tags: c#

I want to replace `"\"` with empty string.  I have tried many things but doesn't work.

MyText like this `test/test\test:test*test?test"test<test>test|test`

```
MyText.Replace("\\\"", "").Replace("\\", "").Replace("\"", "").Replace("\\", "");
```

How to do this in correctly?

Comment: What was the last thing you tried? Cna you post your code and the issues you faced?

Comment: You are on the right track, all you need is `var newStr = MyText.Replace(@"\", "");`. This will replace **all** instances of the backslash in the string.

Comment: Try printing your original string `"test/test\test:test*test?testtest<test>test|test"` - you might be surprised.

Comment: @ColonelPanic it'll be surprised. It doesn't work one line code. Back slash replace code must write a different line

Comment: The escape sequence '\t' means means tab rather than backslash-t.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It should be as simple as the following:

```
string oldStr = "test/test\\test:test*test?test\"test<test>test|test";
string newStr = oldStr.Replace(@"\", string.Empty);
```

Note that I've used the `@` sign to treat the strings as [verbatim string literals](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2004/03/12/what-does-an-before-the-start-of-a-string-literal-mean.aspx). This avoids the need to escape the backslash each time it is used.

**EDIT**
Note also that the Replace function does not replace the contents of the string you call it on. Instead, it returns a new string with the replacement made. I suspect this is the actual cause of your issue, judging by the code you posted.

Comment: @RB Are you sure this will compile?

Comment: @SonerGönül I missed a semicolon off line 1 - anything else I missed? I remembered to escape the `"` halfway through oldStr thought ;-)

Comment: Still won't compile in my Visual Studio and Linqpad. It gives _Newline in constant_ error. Weird!

Comment: I think you should remove `"` middle of the `test\"test` ? This will compile. Looks to me it is not a real string format.

Comment: @RB. you are treating the input string as a literal - it's not.

Comment: @SonerGönül Fixed it :) The issue was that because I was using a string literal, my escaping of the `"` didn't work (because it treats `\"` as a backslash, followed by a quote). I've fixed the code now. I hate having to test stuff because it takes about 5 minutes to start Visual Studio on my machine :(

Comment: @RB. Get yourself an SSD, VS starts in 3 seconds ;)

Comment: @James 3 seconds? No way! What SSD do you use?

Comment: @SonerGönül yes way :) don't want to clog this thread up with irrelevant info, but since you asked I run a [Kingston SSDNow](http://www.cclonline.com/product/45588/SV100S2/64G/Hard-Drives/64GB-Kingston-SSDNow-V-Series-V100-2-5-Solid-State-Drive/HDD1096/) - probably fairly old now in SSD terms, still runs like the wind! Obviously the spec of your machine matters as well I am running it on a Intel Core Duo E8400 @ 3GHz with 4GB RAM Windows 8 box.

Comment: @James I work in a big corporation, so I am using a Windows XP box, with some crappy AMD64 processor, and I had to beg for 3GB RAM. On top of that, it runs so many scanners (AntiVirus, licensing, workspace utilisation) that it can take me 15-20 seconds to open the Start Menu (I really wish I was exagerating there). I have an SSD in my home PC and yes - about 3 seconds is right (even on a Core2Duo@1.7 GHz, with 2GB RAM) :)

Comment: @RB. typical, that's like saying to a fireman "why use a hose when there's a perfectly good bucket here".

Answer (score 1):

Try this out

```
var str = @"test/test\test:test*test?test"test<test>test|test".Replace("\\", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

You could always do:

```
string newString = oldString.Replace("\\", "");
```

Comment: Unless you assign the result of that to something, that effectively does nothing (which was the problem the OP actually had).

Answer (score 0):

I tried it with

```
string test = @"test/test\test\test";
string result = test.Replace("\\", null);
```

and it works fine. 
The result is "test/testtesttest"

Comment: Why would you use `null` when you can use the empty string?

Comment: I thought that he wants to set "real" null-value.

Answer (score 0):

how about

`MyString.Replace(@"\", "");`